# Is $B=(1,1,0) (1,0,1) (0,1,1)$ a basis of $R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $B=\{(1,1,0) (1,0,1) (0,1,1)\}$ a basis of $\mathbb R^3$?

I am doubting how this vector would span $\mathbb R^3$, for example: how will the vector $(2,0,0)$ be in the span of $B$?

I am a beginner, just finished studying bases. This doubt might be very basic, I tried to find on internet but I could not understand much of it. I was looking for some lucid explanation. Thanks.

Comment: $(2,0,0)=(1,1,0)+(1,0,1)-(0,1,1)$

Comment: Ask yourself if the three form a linearly independent set using known techniques (e.g. row reducing).  Conclude that since you have three linearly independent vectors in a three dimensional space, they must span the whole space.

Comment: Another simple way to show that they form a basis is to compute determinant of matrix formed from them, if it's nonzero, they form a basis.

Comment: I understood they were linearly independent... But I cannot quickly understand how they span all vectors.... For example now i am thinking how they would span vectors (1,0,0)... (0,1,0) and (0,0,1)...... I guess it is JMoravitz answer with (1/2) as the scalar multiple....for (1,0,0) isnt it?

Comment: @HarshadaKelkar Yes, that is correct. However, it's important to understand that if they are linearly independent then they're automatically a basis. That's a very important theorem in linear algebra. Of course, knowing they're a basis and computationally finding the coefficients are different questions. I've amended my answer to include comments about that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B=\{(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$ is a base for $\Bbb R^3$.

To verify that, $\forall (x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3$ it must be true that $\exists\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\}\subset \Bbb R$ such that
   $$(x,y,z)=\alpha_1 (1,1,0)+\alpha_2 (1,0,1)+\alpha_3 (0,1,1)$$
By solving a system of equations you will find that
$$\alpha_1=\frac{x+y-z}{2},\ \ \alpha_2=\frac{x-y+z}{2},\ \  \alpha_3=\frac{y-x+z}{2}$$
will do the trick. For instance, when $(x,y,z)=(2,0,0)$, use $\alpha_1=1$, $\alpha_2=1$ and  $\alpha_3=-1$.

It is not possible to show that a set of vectors, such as B, is a base for $\Bbb R^3$ just checking if they span a particular instance from $\Bbb R^3$, such as $(2,0,0)$, this set must span all vectors in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I do not understand your last sentence... "*just checking if they span an **instance** from $\Bbb R^3$*", what do you mean by an instance here?  It is a well known fact that any set of $n$ linearly independent vectors from an $n$-dimensional vector space will serve as a basis for that space.  You do not need to manually verify or compute how to convert from this basis to the standard basis to understand that.

Comment: '@Jmoravitz: thanks for the comment. I've just rewrote the sentence to clarify my thought. In the original post there is no proof of $B$ being a base. My development shows that $B$ is indeed a base. Showing that you can produce a particular vector such as $(2,0,0)$, linearly combining the three vectors in $B$ do not prove that $B$ is a base.

Answer (score 2):

When you have $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, they span the space if and only if they are linearly independent. When you have fewer than $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ they'll never span the space, and when you have more than $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ they'll span the space if there is a subset of size $n$ that is linearly independent. A basis is a spanning set that is also linearly independent, which can only happen when the number of vectors equals the dimension of the space.

You can use any technique you like to see that these vectors are indeed linearly independent (row reduction is popular). Since they are linearly independent and the dimension of the vectors space equals the number of vectors, they form a basis.

For the specific question about $(2,0,0)$, we see that $$(2,0,0)=(1,1,0)+(1,0,1)-(0,1,1)$$ This can be found by solving the equation $$(2,0,0)=a(1,1,0)+b(1,0,1)+c(0,1,1)$$ Although this looks like one equation with three unknowns, we can break it into three equations by looking at each coordinate separately, such as $2=a\cdot 1+b\cdot 1+c\cdot 0$. Once you've broken this into a system of equations, you can solve it via your favorite technique.

Comment: "*When you have more than $n$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ they'll form a basis if...*"  I only recall ever hearing bases being defined in such a way that they must be linearly independent.  A collection of more than $n$ vectors could *span* all of $\Bbb R^n$, but not be a basis for $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for catching that, I meant to be talking about spanning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because for arbitrary $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ we have $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=\frac{a_1+a_2-a_3}{2}(1,1,0)+\frac{a_1+a_3-a_2}{2}(1,0,1)+\frac{a_2+a_3-a_1}{2}(0,1,1)$. The coefficients can be achieved by setting $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=x(1,1,0)+y(1,0,1)+z(0,1,1)$ and solving $(x,y,z)$ in terms of $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$.

Comment: Oh....thanks.... Cannot upvote this because m new with less points, but thanks this helped....... Thanks everybody

Comment: Do u know any good books for such stuff in linear algebra? Is paul halmos good or you would suggest something else for beginners?

Comment: @HarshadaKelkar After reviewing all of the answers, you can accept the one that you think is the best answer by pressing the checkmark button located underneath the up and down arrows. This also marks your question as answered (though people can still leave further answers and comments). As for books, there have been many threads about linear algebra books in this site. You should us the search bar in the upper right corner to search for those threads.